# Numero incremental em PHP

Tags: php, xml

Tenho um sistema que emite um XML. Foi feito em PHP. No XML tem uma *tag* que é um número aleatório, mas tem que ser incremental.

Isto é, na *tag* tem o número 1000. A próxima *tag* tem que ter o número 1001.

Isso é fácil de fazer em PHP. Deixei uma variável fixa e cada vez que ele clica pra emitir, incrementa. Só que todo XML está vindo com número igual, pois está incrementando de uma variável fixa.

Como fazer para cada XML ter seu número incremental?

Comment: Você quer números aleatórios em ordem (1000, 1005, 1154, 1874, 2109...) ou números em ordem somente (1000, 1001, 1002, 1003...)?

Comment: Não sei se compreendi bem, mas tu tens que resgatar o último valor salvo para poder incrementar. Depois põe no loop (for ou foreach).
Outra opção, já que esse número pode ser aleatório, é criar o primeiro número com base no time()

Comment: Preciso de numeros em ordem somente 1000, 1001, 1002.

Comment: Isso, André! Dessa maneira!

Comment: O xml inteiro é gerado em uma requisição ou você quer trabalhar com o XML como se fosse um banco de dados?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom dia, eu sugiro você utilizar um número grande no estilo do Lote de NF-e, é um número com 15 dígitos, desta forma você gera ele a partir da função `microtime()`, por exemplo:

`echo substr(str_replace(',', '', number_format(microtime(true)*1000000, 0)), 0, 15);`

Os créditos são do projeto NFePHP:
https://github.com/nfephp-org/sped-common/blob/master/src/LotNumber/LotNumber.php

Obs.: no meu entendimento, ou é aleatório ou é sequencial, então ou use uma geração aleatória como `mt_rand()` ~ou~ inicie em 1 ou 0 e vai incrementando, eu vejo como conceitos distintos. Se "tem que ser incremental" como você escreveu, então não é aleatório.

Comment: Obrigado era isso mesmo, no caso posso fazer uma variave em cima disso, tipo:
$teste = substr(str_replace(',', '', number_format(microtime(true)*1000000, 0)), 0, 15); ?